# Matching BBcode inside another bbcode (same tag)

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

#### Regex: http://regex101.com/r/uO6jQ3/1

#### String:

`[quote]something [quote]something else[/quote] some text here[/quote]`

#### What the current regex matches:

$matches[6][0]: `[quote]something [quote]something else[/quote]`

#### What it should match:

$matches[6][0]: `[quote]something [quote]something else[/quote] some text here[/quote]`

$matches[6][1]: `[quote]something else[/quote]`

Comment: Do not parse HTML/BBCode/XML with regex. It's forbidden.

Comment: I'm sorry, regex doesn't work that way.

Comment: @hsz: not forbidden, but definitely "unable to handle all possible bbcode markup combinations".

Comment: Be careful trying to parse nested tags with regex. It can summon [unholy ponies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: Even if you __do__ write a regex, it would not give you such desired output! As the nesting is __dynamic__, matches will not come out as groups, but instead as a single-liner.

Comment: What are you trying to do, recursively parse nested `[quote][/quote]` taking off the content along the way, building a hash tree or ? Checking for errors at the same time ? Sure that can be done with regex.

Answer (score 0):

To match a nested structure, you need a recursive pattern, example:

```
$data = '[quote]something [quote]something else[/quote] some text here[/quote]';

$pattern = '~\[quote](?>[^][]+|(?R))*\[/quote]~';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m))
    print_r(m);
```

pattern details:

```
~           # pattern delimiter: do not choose the slash here
\[quote]    #
(?>         # open an atomic group: possible content between tags
    [^][]+  # all that is not a square bracket
  |         # OR
    (?R)    # recurse the whole pattern
)*          # close the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
\[/quote]   #
~
```

Note that it's quite easy. But now if your code may contain other parasite tags between "quote" tags, you only need to change the atomic group to allow them *(written in extended mode)*:

```
(?> [^][]+ | \[/? (?!quote\b) [^]]* ] | (?R) )*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel very ambitious you could sit in a while search loop and build up a nested array of content.  Each new core matched needs to causes a reentrant call into the parse function that executes this regex.

```
 # //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 # // The General Guide to 3-Part Recursive Parsing
 # // ----------------------------------------------
 # // Part 1. CONTENT
 # // Part 2. CORE
 # // Part 3. ERRORS

 (?is)

 (?:
      (                                  # (1), Take off CONTENT
           (?&content) 
      )
   |                                   # OR
      \[quote\]                          # Start-Delimiter
      (                                  # (2), Take off The CORE
           (?&core) 
        |  
      )
      \[/quote\]                         # End-Delimiter

   |                                   # OR
      (                                  # (3), Take off Unbalanced (delimeter) ERRORS
           \[/?quote\]
      )
 )

 # ///////////////////////
 # // Subroutines
 # // ---------------

 (?(DEFINE)

      # core
      (?<core>
           (?>
                (?&content) 
             |  
                \[quote\]
                # recurse core
                (?:
                     (?= . )
                     (?&core) 
                  |  
                )
                \[/quote\]
           )+
      )

      # content 
      (?<content>
           (?>
                (?!
                     \[/?quote\]
                )
                . 
           )+
      )

 )
```

Comment: There is something strange in your pattern, a pipe is alone after `(?&core)`, probably a typo. Or a way to make `(?&core)` optional?

Comment: Not a typo, its required the functions match something, this forces all the alternations to be hit. So we give the core a pass here because it and only it can be empty.

Comment: Btw, that `(?= . )` before the core function call is a Boost regex workaround, otherwise it throws `endless recursion`. I work  with Boost a lot, needless to say have quite a few workarounds.

Comment: I see, but, if I'm not wrong, you don't need to prevent endless recursion with `(?=.)` *(that is here to ensure that there is at least one character)* here because `(?&content)` nor `(?&core)` can't match an empty string. *( `(?&content)` has at least one character, and `(?&core)` has either `(?&content)` or `[quote]...[/quote]`)*

Comment: You are right with other non-Boost engines, like Perl or PHP. The Boost guy Jonh Maddok didn't take it any farther (ie looking downstream for the `|`.

Comment: You'll notice the `(?&core)` is called directly inside `(?<core>)`, there is the problem. At that point his math won't let him continue.

Comment: If I understand well we must therefore show reassuring for the pre-analysis of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build a tree structure. Check out **STML Parser** on the CodeProject. [STML Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855611/Simple-Text-Markup-Language-STML-Parser)